# Form to clasify isolated singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an exercise from Functions of one Complex Variable (2nd edition) of Conway; Chapter 5, exercise 7.

Let $f$ have an isolated singularity at $z=a$ and suppose $f \neq 0$ . Show that if either (1) $Lim_{z\rightarrow a} |z-a|^s|f(z)|=0$ or (2) $Lim_{z\rightarrow a} |z-a|^s|f(z)|=\infty $ holds for some $s \in \mathbb{R}$ then there is an integer $m$ such that (1) holds if $s>m$ and (2) holds if $s<m$.

I guess one way is considering the Laurent expansion of $f(z)=\sum \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} c_n(z-a)^n $ and look $Lim_{z\rightarrow a} \sum \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} c_n(z-a)^{n+s}  $ but I don´t know how to proceed.

Then, the two following exercises (that I could solve), says why this is a form to clasify isolated singularities:

a) $m=0$ iff $z=a$ is a removable singularity and $f(a) \neq 0$

b) $m<0$ iff $z=a$ is a removable singularity and $a$ is a zero of order $-m$

c) $m>0$ iff $z=a$ is a pole of order $m$

d) If neither of the limits is true for any $s \in \mathbb{R}$ , $a$ is an essential singularity

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and not necessarily an integer, then $(z-a)^s$ is not a well-defined function in a neighbourhood of $a$, so you definitely do not want to do that.  On the other hand $|z-a|^s$ makes perfect sense for any $s$.

The key thing you need is this:  If $\lim_{z\to a} |E(z)| = 0$, then $\lim_{z\to a} |z-a|^r|E(z)| = $ for any $r > 0$.  Similarly with infinity, except now the idea is to go the opposite direction.